# joomla html editor on the frontpage

Tags: joomla

I was wondering how one would go about implementing an editor like tinymce so that registered members of a joomla site can post articles, edit them, and get paid when someone downloads them 
like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzlGK.png)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already built into Joomla.

All you need to do to enable this is to add a new "Create Article" menu option with Access = "Registered".

You will probably also need to enable a login module if there isn't one already so users can log in to the front end to see the new menu option.

Comment: My goodness I dont know how I missed that and how might I add the attachment(upload button and system? is it through a form plugin like Rsform pro? Thanks